# Docker osTicket HTTP Errors

Tags: docker, osticket

I'm having troubles getting the Docker containers for osTicket up and running.

I've created and linked the MariaDB and osTicket containers following the getting started directions:

```
$ docker run --name osticket_mysql -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
  -e MYSQL_USER=osticket -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret -e MYSQL_DATABASE=osticket mariadb

$ docker run --name osticket -d --link osticket_mysql:mysql -p 8080:80 osticket/osticket
```

I am then suppose to be able to go to `http://localhost:8080/scp` but I get a HTTP-404 Nginx message.

Going  to `http://localhost:8080` gives me a 403-Restricted Nginx error

The Nginx Error log from inside of the osTicket container is as follows:

```
# cat nginx-error.log 
2018/07/03 01:38:17 [error] 40#40: *1 directory index of "/var/www/src/public/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
2018/07/03 01:38:17 [error] 40#40: *1 open() "/var/www/src/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
2018/07/03 01:38:17 [error] 40#40: *1 open() "/var/www/src/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
2018/07/03 01:41:52 [error] 40#40: *3 directory index of "/var/www/src/public/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
2018/07/03 01:41:52 [error] 40#40: *3 open() "/var/www/src/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
2018/07/03 01:41:52 [error] 40#40: *3 open() "/var/www/src/public/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
2018/07/03 01:45:32 [error] 40#40: *4 directory index of "/var/www/src/public/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
2018/07/03 01:47:21 [error] 40#40: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in /bin/webhook.php on line 12" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /webhook.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What getting started directions did you follow?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/osticket/osticket/ under Quick Start

Comment: It's a 2 years old image, and errors in the logs look application specific. I would imagine that the image is defunct - probably was someone's early attempt to containerize it `osticked` that never worked out.

Comment: Google finds [This one](https://hub.docker.com/r/campbellsoftwaresolutions/osticket/) which looks more up to date, and also gives you at least the login page at `http://localhost:8080/scp/` if you follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSavinykh I should have seen that it was over 2 years old. I loaded the new one and it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

As @AndrewSavinykh pointed out in the comments, the osticket/osticket container image is out of date.

Using the container by Campbell Software Solutions [LINK](https://hub.docker.com/r/campbellsoftwaresolutions/osticket/) solved the issues.